# BES 5.0 and MAPI calls to exchange system

Tags: exchange, blackberry, bes

We have been using BES 4.1(5) for a while now and it has been a resource hog on exchange due to high number of MAPI calls. I have heard that BES 5.0 is even worse. the comparison i heard is that BES 4.1 is makes MAPI calls equal to 5 outlook clients per BB user and BES 5.0 makes MAPI calls equal to 10 outlook clients per BB user.
can someone confirm if it is true? is BES 5.0 is really that bad in MAPI calls and for exchange performance. ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With BES 5.0 and Exchange 2010 BES is similar to one Outlook 2007 client in online mode per user.

RIM has a guide that shows the load requirements under different environments:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/8864/BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server_for_Microsoft_Exchange-5.0-US.pdf